# Java applet running all-perminssions gets BlockedException: User has denied the privileges to the code

Tags: java, javascript, applet, manifest

I'm about to build a website where we'll use a java applet. To be able to do everything we need we want  to run the applet in all-permission. This is because we need to print, communicat to Comport and read files from the local system from website. But have som problem with the permissions.

I have filled in the most important things in the MANIFEST file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.1
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.1
Created-By: 1.7.0_06  (Name)
Main-Class: Applet
Class-Path: lib/jcl.jar lib/jpos113-controls.jar lib/stario.jar lib/st
            arjavapos.jar lib/xercesimpl.jar lib/xml-apis.jar
Application-Name: Java Applet
Codebase: http://10.0.1.4/github/store/inc/applet/
Permissions: all-permissions
```

I have also self-signed the main JAR file using "jarsigner".(will buy proper certificate later) The main JAR file consisting of several other JAR files.

When applet runs in browser a safety box came up with information that the applet will run with unlimited restriction and ask if I wanted to do it or not.

I Chose to run it, and everything looks good until I try to run for example: a printer class in one of the jars in my lib folder. The following error message shows in log:

```
com.sun.deploy.security.BlockedException: User has denied the privileges to the code
```

I have also tried to run privileged code within: (without success)

```
  AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction() {
        public Object run() {
            // privileged code goes here, for example:
            // Example..
            return null; 
        }
    });
```

Anyone have an idea what could be wrong? Or have any tips?

Obs,Works if I run it directly in netbeans.

// Kind regards

Comment: Ever figure this out? Having the same issue trying to run an applet in my page.